# Rails 4 - Making profile pages sharable

Tags: ruby-on-rails

SOLUTION:

I changed this line of code and now it displays perfectly.

```
<% if answer.user == current_user %>
```

to

```
<% if answer.user == @user %>
```

I posted a similar question last night but this is a new one.

I am building a question/answer app.  The questions are static and provided, not user generated.  The data is being accessed via a nested relationship.

On the individual user page, I am showing the questions/answers for that specific user using the code below.  It is working great.  Unfortunately, I want users to be able to share their profile pages and with the way things are set up, users can only see their own stuff, not that of others.  What do I need to change so that only the data for user 1 is displayed on /users/1 but user 2 can view it?

I am assuming it will have something to do with using params to find the user vs. current_user, but I'm not sure how to set it up.

Here is the code in my show.view.

```
<% @user.questions.uniq.each do |question| %>
  <h3><div class="answer"><%= question.question %> </div></h3>
    <% question.answers.each do |answer| %>
    <% if answer.user == current_user %>
      <div class="answer"><%= answer.answer %> <%= answer.created_at.strftime("(%Y)") %></div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

My models:

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :user
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers
  has_many :users, through: :answers
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers
  has_many :questions, through: :answers
end
```

My Routes:

```
resources :users do
  resources :answers
end
```

I'm happy to provide any other code that would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: So you say, if One user answers the question, only he sees his answer and nobody else?

Comment: The way it is set up now, on the user pages (/user/1) that is how it works. Only user 1 can see it.  But, I want people to be able to share their user pages so I need to display the data for only user 1 on /user/1 while still making it visible to user 2

Comment: Okay, so you need in question controller make a request to find every answer which matches questions id. And then implement that in questions view something like this <%= render partial: "question", collection: @answers, as: answer %>

Comment: Just to make this clearer the request will look something like this: @answers = Answer.all.where("question_id = ?", question_id), you maybe need to add a column to Answer db to correspond to question id.

Comment: This isn't happening on the questions view, it is happening on the users.show view.  I don't see where this is filtering out so that only the answers by a specific user are shown on a specific page.  I don't know where I would put this in my code or what it would replace.  Could you create an answer with the code as you think it should look now vs a comment?  There is already a question_id column on the answers table. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Okay, then you need to have in your show method in user controller something like this:

```
@answers_to_one_question = Answer.all.where("question_id = ?", question_id)
or 
@answers_to_one_question = User.all.answers.where("question_id = ?", question_id)
```

And in the show view something like this:

```
<%= render partial: "answer", collection: @answers_to_one_question, as: answer  %>
```

I didn't test this code, but the logic is like this.

Comment: so what part of my view code would this replace?  all of it?  I'm sorry, but I'm just learning so I'm not clear on what needs to be changed in the view. thanks

Comment: Well, I would recommend to do a answer render look here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html, and in the view add code, that is in the answer.But the logic is that you just need to apply that array , which you made a request in your controller to view.